# Android edittext menu like Chrome actionbar

Tags: android, android-edittext, menuitem

Hi I would like to know how the [Cut Copy Paste] menu on Android Google Chrome is made. What's it called? I would be happy to read on the documentation for this view but I can't seem to find the right keywords to search with.

If anyone can point me in the right direction, it would be very much appreciated.

Thank you!

[image: Cut Copy Paste menu]

Comment: It is known as a popup menu

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. But from what I understand, a popup menu will show a vertical list of menu items. And from my research I don't think that this is one. But I'll review the docs again. :)

Comment: A popup menu can show whatever you want it to show. ;)

Comment: I see, I'll try that. Thank you very much